# How to debug multiple console applications with VSCode in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, debugging, console

I have a solution with multiple console apps and I want to debug the selected one like in Visual Studio. Is there a  way to do it?

I found that the only way for me was to delete launch.json and add it to the current project every time. But that is not very convenient.

Comment: All configuration from the launch.json are shown in the dropdown on the "Run and Debug" page. Simple select the one you want to launch there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution. The only problem with adding projects to the `launch.json` file is that I have a lot of projects with a lot of folders and long names.

The solution I've found is really simple! Because I use C# extension there is a setting in the User Settings - `CSharp > Debug: Console`, there I changed it to `integratedTerminal` and it fixed the issue. Now I can debug any app without using `.vscode` and read from the console.

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The `configurations` key in launch.json is an array. You can have multiple configurations in the launch.json, one (or more) for each of your console applications. You can read about this [in the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_add-a-new-configuration)

For example:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ConsoleApp1",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp1.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ConsoleApp1",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": "ConsoleApp2",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ConsoleApp2/bin/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp2.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/ConsoleApp2",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

After doing this, the Run and Debug dropdown will have multiple configurations. You can select the first one and start it, and then while the first one is running, go back and select the second one, and so on.

[image: screenshot of the run and debug dropdown showing multiple configurations]